# Способы добавления картинки в html под различные разрешения экрана и влияние на скорость загрузки страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, изображения, адаптивная-верстка

Таким образом я доабавляю картинку с адаптацией под различные экраны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: загружаться на устройство при открытии страницы из них будет будет только одна? Или сразу все? Потому что все эти картинки весят 1.5 мегабайта и если они все будут загружаться это сильно повлияет на скорость загрузки сайта.
А в случае если я их добавлю через css background в медизапросах? Скорость загрузки будет такая же как и в 1 случае?

Comment: Загрузится одна. А ещё можно открыть вкладку  network  в инструментах разработчика и узреть это воочию

Comment: спасибо, можешь ответить как ответ и я отмечу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коротко:

Тег `source` используется для определения нескольких файлов-ресурсов в тегах `video`, `audio` или `picture`. В вашем случае это тег `picture`.

Атрибут `srcset` указывает адрес медиа-файла (в вашем случае это URL-адрес изображения).

Атрибут `media` определяет условие, при котором этот источник будет использован. Любой современный браузер самостоятельно выбирает (ответ на ваш вопрос: ***загружает на устройство. Остальные медиа-файлы при этом не будут загружены***) наиболее подходящий источник из списка в соответствии с условием.

---

Рекомендация:

Дополнительно предлагаю использовать атрибут `sizes`, который устанавливает размеры изображения в зависимости от `media`-условия. Вот самый простой пример его использования:

```
<img srcset="demo.jpg 600w,
             demo.jpg 800w,
             demo.jpg 1200w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 520px,
            (max-width: 800px) 720px,
            1200px"
     src="demo.jpg">
```

Более подробную информацию об атрибуте `sizes` и его использовании можно найти на просторах Интернета.